# Why is microk8s failing to install?

Tags: apple-m1, microk8s, macos-monterey

I'm trying to use microk8s for my KubernetesPodOperator in my dag. Unfortunately I can't seem get it to install consistently.

I'm using homebrew to install (or reinstall) microk8s and multipass. When I execute

`microk8s install --cpu=4 --mem=10000`

I get the errors:

```
launch failed: The following errors occurred:                                   
qemu-system-aarch64: Error: HV_BAD_ARGUMENT

launch failed: instance "microk8s-vm" already exists


An error occurred with the instance when trying to launch with 'multipass': returned exit code 2.
Ensure that 'multipass' is setup correctly and try again.
```

(where `launch failed: instance "microk8s-vm" already exists` appears several times.)

I've tried reinstalling both several times and that doesn't appear to help. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I need to be using `microk8s install --cpu=4 --mem=10` not 10000. It wants GB, not MB. My bad. I wish the error message was a little clearer though.